# Django TypeError: 'bar' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, mongodb

So, i used to have 2 models in the same app working fine, but when i moved both models to different classes each i can't get the ForeignKey to work it seems. The model in question:

```
from app1.models import Bar

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('...............')
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, editable=False, verbose_name=_('Bar'))
```

But when i try:

```
>>>f = Foo(name='name', bar=existing_bar).save()
```

I get

```
TypeError: 'bar' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Im using mongodb with django. I don't understand why it worked flawlessly when they were on the same app, but now not :/

I noticed in my old collection that foo documents had a bar_id field and now not, for what it's worth.

Comment: Can you provide your actual models rather than obfuscated versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure why this is happening, there could be something mentioned in django docs, but for now you can supply an `__init__` to keep it working -

for python 3+

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('...............')
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, editable=False, verbose_name=_('Bar'))

    def __init__(self, *args, bar=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar
```

for python 2.6+

```
 class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('...............')
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, editable=False, verbose_name=_('Bar'))

    def __init__(self, *args, bar=None, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar
```